# Why can I only see "Super Admins" in the Communicate interface?

Tags: email, groups

I am working on a site with several (20+) member groups. The administrator would like to send an email via Tools > Communicate to one of the member groups. However, only the “Super Admins” under “Member Groups” in the email interface. Why would all the other member groups not be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to enable this preference on the Edit Member Group page:

> Allow Members in Site's Mailing Lists and Related Abilities? (i.e. Group Available in Communicate section)